# Java Script PHP зависимый список

Tags: javascript, php

**`Sql`** подключена правильно, не понимаю как все это соединить((

**`Sql`** с использованием `RedBean`

```
$marks = R::findAll('mark', 'ORDER BY title ASC');    
        $model = R::findAll('model', 'ORDER BY title ASC');
```

PHP файл.

```
<h3>Марка</h3>
                <label>
                    <select id="full_mark" class="select2" name="mark">
                        <option value="0" selected>Все марки</option>
                        <?php if (isset($marks)): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($marks as $mark): ?>
                                <option value="<?=$mark['id']; ?>"><?=$mark['title']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <!--Модель-->

            <div class="FullModel">
                <h3>Модель</h3>
                <label>
                    <select id="full_model" class="select2" name="model">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Выберите модель</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
```

Java Script.

```
    function getModel(parent, mark, model, create=0) {
        $(parent).on('change',mark, function () {
            var mark_id = $(mark).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    mark_id: mark_id,
                    create: create,
                },

                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res) {
                        $(model).empty().html(res)
                    } else {
                        $(model).empty().html('<option>Нет моделей</option>')
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Ошибка');
                }
            });
        });
    }


    getModel('#search', '#mark', '#model');
```

Код выдает ошибку.

Страница исполнения https://example.com/index

Comment: Если аякс получает ответ со второго блока, то изменить `dataType: 'json',` на `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: @Json  Файл где работает скрипт имеет разрешение PHP, соответственно ставить dataType: 'php', ???

Comment: Нет. JS не знает что такое PHP. Расширение файла на это никак не влияет. Файл отдаёт контент в формате HTML - ставить dataType:'html'. Если бы файл отдавал контент в фрмате JSON - тогда dataType: 'json'. Для xml - dataType: 'xml'.

Comment: @Json все равно не работает(((

Comment: Тогда надо открывать консоль браузера и смотреть какой ответ вернул сервер

Comment: @Json что интересно, он вроде пытается вывести модели, но поле просто становится пустым, даже фраза "Выберите модель" исчезает. А как с помощью браузера посмотреть? В "Просмотре кода" или где?

Comment: Да, "Просмотр кода", вкладка "Сеть" (Networks), фильтр "XHR"

Comment: @Json   выводи следующее: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. и Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Ок. Нам нужна `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404` 404 - это страница не найдена. То-есть, ссылка в параметрах `url: '/'`, указанных в аяксе, недействительна. Тут лучше отредактировать топик и дополнить информацией: какой фреймворк используется на бекэнде; как обрабатывается роутинг; как возвращается ответ; в каких случаях возвращается 404 и тд; желательно с фрагментами кода

Comment: @Json то есть нужно вписать полный адрес страницы? Пример: https://mywebsite.com/Page  ??? Бекэнд не использует никаких фреймворков, чистый код в процедурном виде.

Comment: Можно полный адрес, можно и `/path/to/file.php`. Если эта 404 ошибка имеет отношение именно к этому аяксу (не фавикон и не несуществующий какой-нибудь файл стилей) - теоретически: запрос был отправлен на файл index.php (если конфиг апача не менялся) . В каких случаях сервер возвращает код 404 при переходе на страницу `index.php`? Без полного кода проекта - это будет гаданием на кофейной гуще. Если проект не сильно секретный выложите весь код куданибудь и киньте сюда ссылку